# How to check multiple values in an array with AND , OR operators

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to see if an array has one or more values inside it and I want to pass check my values are in that array. I'm going to use it to check role permissions in a system.

example input-output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].include?([4,1])   => true
[4,1,6,2].include?([4,1])       => true
[3,4,7].include?([4,1])         => false
```

I tried to solve it using `in_array()`:

```
if(!$auth->checkPermissions([1,3])) {
    echo json_encode(['Result'=>false,'Type'=>'ERROR','Message'=>UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS]);
    exit;
}

public static function checkPermissions($permissionLevels = []){
    $userPermission =[1,4,5,6];

    foreach($permissionLevels as $permission){
        if (in_array($permission,$userPermission)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is happening because you only checking **1** permission as you use `return` in the `foreach`.

You should do it like this:

```
public static function checkPermissions($permissionLevels = []){
    $userPermission =[1,4,5,6];
    foreach($permissionLevels as $permission){
        if (!in_array($permission,$userPermission))
            return false; // if one is missing decline
    }
    return true; // if got here mean all found
}
```

You can also use [array-intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) as:

```
function checkPermissions($permissionLevels = []){
        $userPermission =[1,4,5,6];
        $permissionLevels = array_unique($permissionLevels);
        return count(array_intersect($permissionLevels, $userPermission)) == count($permissionLevels));
}
```

**Do notice** to use `array_unique` if using the `array_intersect` as you can have duplicate - consider case where `checkPermissions([4,4]);`

Comment: Do you think this will work ?> `return (array_intersect($permissionLevels, $userPermission) == $permissionLevels);`

Answer (score -1):

Just compare the intersection of the two with the permissions to be checked:

```
return array_intersect($permissionLevels, $userPermission) == $permissionLevels;
```

See the [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Aadkr).

Comment: I just also add that to my answer as the better way to do what the OP want

Comment: Do you think this will work ?> `return (array_intersect($permissionLevels, $userPermission) == $permissionLevels);`

Comment: @RakeshJakhar, yes you just added `()`

Comment: try both [4,1] and [1,4]...see the result in both cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193273/discussion-between-rakesh-jakhar-and-abracadaver).